# Creating a percentage column to a table that is not in the From clause through PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, percentage

I am working with a bike share dataset located [here](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) and [here](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/202004-divvy-tripdata.zip) is a sample month of it.
I want to get the percent of rides per day per membership type, so I applied this query through PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT  Start_day,
        member_casual AS Membership,  
        COUNT(*) AS Trips_Count, 
        (COUNT(*) / (SELECT count(*) from rides)) AS Trips_percent, 
        AVG(duration) AS Average_Trip_Duration
FROM (SELECT member_casual,  
      ended_at - started_at AS duration, 
      EXTRACT(DOW from started_at) AS Start_day_num, 
      TO_CHAR(started_at,'DY') AS Start_day 
      FROM rides
     ) AS member_duration
GROUP BY Start_day, Start_day_num, member_casual 
ORDER BY Start_day_num, Trips_Count;
```

The query returned all the fields correct, except the `Trips_percent` it is all zeros!

I searched through several solutions; I found one suggesting to define the sum first through WITH clause, then use it in the query as follows:

```
WITH total AS 
    (SELECT COUNT(member_casual) AS records 
     FROM rides)
SELECT  Start_day,
        member_casual AS Membership,  
        COUNT(*) AS Trips_Count, 
        (COUNT(*) / total.records) AS Trips_percent, 
        AVG(duration) AS Average_Trip_Duration
FROM (SELECT member_casual,  
      ended_at - started_at AS duration, 
      EXTRACT(DOW from started_at) AS Start_day_num, 
      TO_CHAR(started_at,'DY') AS Start_day 
      FROM rides
     ) AS member_duration
GROUP BY Start_day, Start_day_num, member_casual 
ORDER BY Start_day_num, Trips_Count;
```

Unfortunately it gave me the following error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "total"
LINE 7:   (count(*) / total.records) AS Trips_percent, 
                      ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 178
```

Is it because the `FROM` clause in the main query does not refer to the table of the `WITH` query?

What is wrong with either query and how can I do to solve them?

Comment: That's correct.  CTE terms are just a form of table available for reference by subsequent CTE terms or the final query expression.  The corresponding FROM clause needs to refer to any necessary tables, including those defined by CTE terms.

Comment: The problem with the query is most likely that you’re doing integer division. Any number divided by a larger number is zero since it’s smaller then the divisor. If you want percentage you should multiply by 100 before division, or cast into floats. PostgreSQL especially is strict with data types, which is a good thing.

Comment: Yes, @SamiKuhmonen, this was the problem, when I multiplied by 100.0, the problem was solved. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @JonArmstrong for your comment, but I do not know what is a CTE!

Comment: CTE is Common Table Expression (WITH clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest phrasing this as a window function.  But the key is avoiding integer division:

```
SELECT Start_day,
       member_casual AS Membership,  
       COUNT(*) AS Trips_Count, 
       (COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS Trips_percent, 
       AVG(duration) AS Average_Trip_Duration
FROM (SELECT member_casual,  
             ended_at - started_at AS duration, 
             EXTRACT(DOW from started_at) AS Start_day_num, 
             TO_CHAR(started_at,'DY') AS Start_day 
      FROM rides
     ) AS member_duration
GROUP BY Start_day, Start_day_num, member_casual 
ORDER BY Start_day_num, Trips_Count;
```

Comment: This solved my problem, with one modification, to multiply by 100.0, not 1.0, to get the percentage.